# How to remove action with slashes and arrows?

Tags: filters, hooks, actions

I have two actions like `BSF_AIOSRS_Pro_Markup–>disable_astra_theme_schema` and `'Yoast\WP\SEO\Integrations\Front_End\Redirects–>archive_redirect'` on 'wp'. But I can't remove these both as usually like:

```php
remove_action('wp', 'BSF_AIOSRS_Pro_Markup–>disable_astra_theme_schema', 10);
remove_action('wp', 'Yoast\WP\SEO\Integrations\Front_End\Redirects–>archive_redirect', 10);
```

How I can remove these actions with \ and -> and other things? Thanks for help.

PS. Using Google for solving the problem but it's doesn't help me :(

Comment: Hi I know this is an old post but did you ever resolve this? Having the same issue. Thanks

Comment: it might be better to contact Yoast SEO support and ask them how to disable archive redirects, 3rd party plugin dev support is offtopic here and you can't ask for help with products you downloaded and installed here

Answer (score 0):

`remove_action` needs a callable, and it has to be the same as when the action was added.

So the answer to how you remove an action with a `->` is you don't, because that's not a part of the action, it's just PHP syntax.

Instead you need:

```php
[ $theobject, 'the function name' ]
```

So for `BSF_AIOSRS_Pro_Markup–>disable_astra_theme_schema` you need to figure out where that plugin keeps the object of type `BSF_AIOSRS_Pro_Markup` and use that as the first variable aka `$theobject`, and then use `'disable_astra_theme_schema'` where I put `the function name`.

In some situations, this might not be possible due to poor quality plugins. If that happens you need to contact them or fork the plugin.